# Windows Phone Toast Notification Not Shown

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone, windows-phone-8

I have a toast notification set up to be shown at a set time in my app. When that time comes, the toast doesn't show, even when the app is not running in the foreground. What can I do to make the toast display when the app isn't running in the foreground? I also know that the toast won't show when the app is running in the foreground because it is set up that way. But it won't show when I'm on the Start Screen either.

```
ShellToast toast = new ShellToast();
toast.Title = "Title";
toast.Content = "The Time has come!";
toast.Show();
```

So Basically my question is how can I make the toast notification show when the app is not running the foreground (Plus is the app even running when I go to the start screen?) Thanks for any answers!